# Error: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-maven-plugin

I am new to Android with maven environment. I am trying to run a sample application, but I am having problems. When I select the Project and do **MAVEN->Clean Install**, I get following Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:andr
oid-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project ut
ils-android: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins
.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources failed: A requi
red class was missing while executing com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generatio
n2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositoryS
ystem;
```

Please, not I have 3.1.1 version of Meven, also I am using Eclipse on Windows 7 system.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Maven is your Eclipse configured to run? You might need to manually point it to your local install of Maven 3.1

Comment: Hi, I am using 3.1.1 as mentioned above. I have Created the system variable to point to maven folder. When I run mvn -version, it shows me the correct version of Maven & JDK.

Comment: How could i manually point it to local install? plz. let me know. thanks

Comment: Please note that the Eclipse m2e plugin comes with its own, internal version of Maven installed which might be different to the version of Maven installed on your PATH. You need to configure Eclipse to use that version of Maven http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#What_Maven_version_is_used_by_plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ricardo Gladwell: Thanks for your replies.

Actually I had to reinstall maven 3.0.5 to avoide this error. But before that I completly removed .m2 directory from /Users/Username/ folder.